# asp.net 5 / mvc 6 / model binder / angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, modelbinder

I do not know because when I do a post by angular, objects are not populated, such as categories or status. Just the product.
However, note that the Request.Form list, the information is there.
The binder is not performed correctly.
What am I doing wrong?
Is it any web api configuration?
I've tried sending data via application/json, [frombody] ... I'm out of options.
Thanks in advance.

```js
var product = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Name",
  categories: [
    { id: 1, name: "name 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "name 2" }
  ],
  status: { id: 1, name: "active" }
};

var config: ng.IRequestConfig;
config = { url: "", method: "POST", headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;' } };

self.$http.post("api/produto", $.param(product), config)
.success(function () {
  alert("OK");
});
```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ProductInfo Post(ProductInfo item)
    {
        return item;
    }
```

[model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hukLT.png)

[request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo3pB.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$http({
        url: "api/produto",
        method: "POST",
        data: product,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
            // failed
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the shortcut method:

```
$http.post('api/produto', data).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try

```
var product = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Name",
  categories: [
    { id: 1, name: "name 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "name 2" }
  ],
  status: { id: 1, name: "active" }
};

var config: ng.IRequestConfig;
config = { url: "", method: "POST", headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;' } };

self.$http.post("api/produto", product, config)
.success(function () {
  alert("OK");
});
```

What is different is that I send the actual JavaScript object and it will be serialized as JSON. Web API will be able to deserialize the JSON into a pure C# object.

Trying to match key/value pair is normally just madness on complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

There was no way to do it.

Either I create a custom model binder, or I'll have the new web api 6 mvc always use the `frombody` and force the ship by json.

At least that's what I did with my tests.
It worked just sending json and using `frombody`.

The documentation, really changed bind the web api 2 for this new integrated model to MVC.